# Castle Windsor Service Override in XML configuration

Tags: castle-windsor, xml-configuration

I am using xml configuration to set up components in Castle Windsor.  I have this config:

```
  <component id="SurescriptsDatabase"

    service="System.Data.IDbConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"
    type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" lifestyle="transient">
    <parameters>
      <connectionString>REDACTED1</connectionString>
    </parameters>
  </component>
  <component id="Surescriptsv10Database"
    service="System.Data.IDbConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"
    type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" lifestyle="transient">
    <parameters>
      <connectionString>REDACTED2</connectionString>
    </parameters>
  </component>
  <component id="Surescriptsv10StagingDatabase"
    service="System.Data.IDbConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"
    type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" lifestyle="transient">
    <parameters>
      <connectionString>REDACTED3</connectionString>
    </parameters>
  </component>

  <component id="SurescriptsWatcher" 
             type="PatientFirst.Framework.Services.ScalarQueryWatcher, PatientFirst.Framework.Services">
    <parameters>
      <Database>${SurescriptsDatabase}</Database>
      <Frequency>0.00:01:00</Frequency>
      <CustomMessage>Surescripts v6 is not running</CustomMessage>
      <Query>select count(1) from [SureScripts_Production].[dbo].[ToSureScriptMessagesQueue] where requesttime &lt; dateadd(minute,-1,getdate()) and responsetime is null</Query>
      <MinResult>-1</MinResult>
      <MaxResult>0</MaxResult>
    </parameters>
  </component>
  <component id="Surescriptsv10Watcher" type="PatientFirst.Framework.Services.ScalarQueryWatcher, PatientFirst.Framework.Services">
    <parameters>
      <Database>${Surescriptsv10Database}</Database>
      <Frequency>0.00:01:00</Frequency>
      <CustomMessage>Surescripts v10 is not running</CustomMessage>
      <Query>select count(1) from [SureScripts_v10_Production].[dbo].[ToSureScriptMessagesQueue] where requesttime &lt; dateadd(minute,-1,getdate()) and responsetime is null</Query>
      <MinResult>-1</MinResult>
      <MaxResult>0</MaxResult>
    </parameters>
  </component>
  <component id="Surescriptsv10StagingWatcher" type="PatientFirst.Framework.Services.ScalarQueryWatcher, PatientFirst.Framework.Services">
    <parameters>
      <Database>${Surescriptsv10StagingDatabase}</Database>
      <Frequency>0.00:01:00</Frequency>
      <CustomMessage>Surescripts v10 Staging is not running</CustomMessage>
      <Query>select count(1) from [SureScripts_v10_Staging].[dbo].[ToSureScriptMessagesQueue] where requesttime &lt; dateadd(minute,-1,getdate()) and responsetime is null</Query>
      <MinResult>-1</MinResult>
      <MaxResult>0</MaxResult>
    </parameters>
  </component>
```

In my constructor for my ScalarQueryWatcher I am always getting the same database connection being injected.  If I remove the service= portion of the component definitions for the SQLConections then Windsor complains with:

> Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException: Can't create component >'serviceBootstrapper' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
>
> 'SurescriptsWatcher' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>   - Service 'System.Data.IDbConnection' which was not registered.
>   - Component 'Surescriptsv10Watcher' (via override) which was registered but is also waiting for dependencies.
>
> 'Surescriptsv10Watcher' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>   - Service 'System.Data.IDbConnection' which was not registered.
>   - Component 'Surescriptsv10StagingWatcher' (via override) which was registered but is also waiting for dependencies.
>
> 'Surescriptsv10StagingWatcher' is waiting for the following
>   dependencies:
>   - Service 'System.Data.IDbConnection' which was not registered.

What am I doing wrong here?  From reading the documentation I thought that specifying the `<Database>${SurescriptsDatabase}</Database>` using the id of the component would give me that particular component.

---

UPDATE
Meant to do this earlier, here you go for later posterity.  The problem did not lie within the XML configuration, but within the source code:

Public Class ScalarQueryWatcher

```
Public Sub New(ByVal Query As String,
 ByVal Connection As IDbConnection,
 ByVal Frequency As TimeSpan,
 ByVal MinResult As Integer, ByVal MaxResult As Integer)
    _database = Connection
    'this should get the table we're querying from
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Query) Then Throw New ApplicationException("Query cannot be null")
    _queryName = Query.Substring(Query.IndexOf("FROM", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) + 5)
    If _queryName.Contains(" ") Then _queryName = _queryName.Substring(0, _queryName.IndexOf(" "))
    _query = Query
    _frequency = Frequency
    _minResult = MinResult
    _maxResult = MaxResult
    _range = _maxResult - _minResult
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide the signature of the ScalarQueryWatcher constructor(s)?

Comment: You hit it on the head Patrick, I meant to update this later the same day, but forgot about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the constructor parameter name is Connection, not Database as I had referenced it in the xml configuration.  That is the reason it "worked" when the service type was specified, it would grab whatever matched an IDbConnection.  When I started using the correct constructor parameter name i got the database I specified by id.

```
Public Sub New(ByVal Query As String,
 ByVal Connection As IDbConnection,         'Note the name here is Connection
 ByVal Frequency As TimeSpan,
 ByVal MinResult As Integer, ByVal MaxResult As Integer)
    _database = Connection
    'this should get the table we're querying from
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Query) Then Throw New ApplicationException("Query cannot be null")
    _queryName = Query.Substring(Query.IndexOf("FROM", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) + 5)
    If _queryName.Contains(" ") Then _queryName = _queryName.Substring(0, _queryName.IndexOf(" "))
    _query = Query
    _frequency = Frequency
    _minResult = MinResult
    _maxResult = MaxResult
    _range = _maxResult - _minResult
End Sub

  <component id="SurescriptsWatcher" 
             type="PatientFirst.Framework.Services.ScalarQueryWatcher, PatientFirst.Framework.Services">
    <parameters>
      <Database>${SurescriptsDatabase}</Database>  <!--note the parameter here is database, which does not match the constructor parameter -->
      <Frequency>0.00:01:00</Frequency>
      <CustomMessage>Surescripts v6 is not running</CustomMessage>
      <Query>select count(1) from [SureScripts_Production].[dbo].[ToSureScriptMessagesQueue] where requesttime &lt; dateadd(minute,-1,getdate()) and responsetime is null</Query>
      <MinResult>-1</MinResult>
      <MaxResult>0</MaxResult>
    </parameters>
  </component>
```

Comment: Thanks @BlackICE! It's one of those little things with Castle that's so hard to spot...